# my home folder is infested with /.folder and /.temp

Tags: home-directory

it's littering the home page, making the navigation chaotic.

[image: here whats look like]

i dont know what to do. please help

Comment: Why are you seeing the ./ files in the first place? You only see these if you turn on hidden files display. Ctrl -H Why do you need this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are *normal* to see in a Linux environment if you aren't hiding hidden files.  They are created by various programs to store data in your user profile.

They are TYPICALLY hidden - in Linux, prefixing a directory or file with a `.` marks it to be hidden.  Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see if that hides the items from view.  There should also be an option from the hamburger menu (the button with three horizonal lines in a 'hamburger' like pattern) that says "Show Hidden Files" - and you should uncheck that to hide those dot-files as they are typically called.

**Deleting them will remove your settings and files, which will cause problems if you intend to use your applications. such as Thunderbird and keep your mail.**  DO NOT delete the files and folders.

Comment: Yeah! That worked fine! Thanks, man!

Comment: @Roninhu glad to hear it.  Hit the checkmark on the left side of my post underneath the voting buttons to mark this as the accepted answer.